# How do add a bottom boarder to UIView Class?

Tags: swift, xcode, uiview, border

I have a view class that I apply to various UIViews in UITableViews throughout my Storyboard.

```
class ListContainerView: UIView {

override func awakeFromNib() {
    super.awakeFromNib()
    
    // Set the thickness of the border
    let thickness: CGFloat = 0.5
    
    // Set the color of the border
    let color: CGColor = UIColor.lightGray.cgColor
    
    // Add top border to the ListContainerView
    let topBorder = CALayer()
    topBorder.frame = CGRect(x: 0.0, y: 0.0, width: self.frame.size.width, height: thickness)
    topBorder.backgroundColor = color
    self.layer.addSublayer(topBorder)
    
    // Add bottom border to ListContainerView
    let bottomBorder = CALayer()
    bottomBorder.frame = CGRect(x: 0.0, y: self.frame.size.height - thickness, width: self.frame.size.width, height: thickness)
    bottomBorder.backgroundColor = color
    self.layer.addSublayer(bottomBorder)
    
}

}
```

As of now, the code properly adds a top border to the UIView. However, it is not adding the bottom border. I have tried numerous tactics from various StackOverflow answers but none have been successful. What am I doing incorrectly? How can I go about resolving this issue?

UPDATE: I have corrected the initial typo in my code. Additionally, here is a screenshot of an example of where this view is being accessed. In the screenshot, both of the Post View(s) are assigned the class ListContainerView.

[image: Screenshot of Main.storyboard]

Thank you in advance for any help you are able to provide!

Comment: are you adding this `UIView` in your `UITableviewCell`?

Comment: The Y position is self.frame.size.width - thickness?  Does that make sense?

Comment: show where you are adding this view ?

Comment: @DharmeshKheni yes I am

Comment: @ElTomato That was actually a typo on my end. Thank you for pointing that out. Unfortunately, after updating the code, it is still not working.

Comment: @jawadAli I have attached a screenshot to show an example of where I am adding this view.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actually, I have the following `UIView` subclass similar to yours.  Try it.  It always works.

```
import UIKit

class TopBotView: UIView {
    override func draw(_ rect: CGRect) {
        let tHeight = self.frame.size.height
        let topLayer = CALayer()
        topLayer.frame = CGRect(x: 0.0, y: tHeight - 0.5, width: self.frame.size.width, height: 0.5)
        topLayer.backgroundColor = UIColor.white.withAlphaComponent(0.3).cgColor
        topLayer.masksToBounds = true
        self.layer.addSublayer(topLayer)
        
        let bottomLayer = CALayer()
        bottomLayer.frame = CGRect(x: 0.0, y: 0.0, width: self.frame.size.width, height: 0.5)
        bottomLayer.backgroundColor = UIColor.white.withAlphaComponent(0.3).cgColor
        bottomLayer.masksToBounds = true
        self.layer.addSublayer(bottomLayer)
    }
}
```

**UPDATE**

If you want to surround all sides with a thin line, I have the following subclass.

```
import UIKit

class AllAroundView: UIView {
    override func draw(_ rect: CGRect) {
        let tHeight = self.frame.size.height
        let topLayer = CALayer()
        topLayer.frame = CGRect(x: 0.0, y: tHeight - 0.5, width: self.frame.size.width, height: 0.5)
        topLayer.backgroundColor = UIColor.black.cgColor
        topLayer.masksToBounds = true
        self.layer.addSublayer(topLayer)
        
        let bottomLayer = CALayer()
        bottomLayer.frame = CGRect(x: 0.0, y: 0.0, width: self.frame.size.width, height: 0.5)
        bottomLayer.backgroundColor = UIColor.black.cgColor
        bottomLayer.masksToBounds = true
        self.layer.addSublayer(bottomLayer)
        
        let leftLayer = CALayer()
        leftLayer.frame = CGRect(x: 0.0, y: 0.0, width: 0.5, height: self.frame.size.height)
        leftLayer.backgroundColor = UIColor.black.cgColor
        leftLayer.masksToBounds = true
        self.layer.addSublayer(leftLayer)
        
        let rightLayer = CALayer()
        rightLayer.frame = CGRect(x: self.frame.size.width - 0.5, y: 0.0, width: 0.5, height: self.frame.size.height)
        rightLayer.backgroundColor = UIColor.black.cgColor
        rightLayer.masksToBounds = true
        self.layer.addSublayer(rightLayer)
    }
}
```

Comment: That works; thank you! I am guessing that my problem had something to do with me using awakeFromNib instead of draw.

Comment: That's good for you.  If you want to surround all sides with a thin line, I have a subclass called AllAroundView.

Answer (score 1):

```
bottomBorder.frame = CGRect(x: 0.0, y: self.frame.size.width - thickness, width: self.frame.size.width, height: thickness)
```

shouldn't it be

```
bottomBorder.frame = CGRect(x: 0.0, y: self.frame.size.height - thickness, width: self.frame.size.width, height: thickness)
```

unless your UIView is a square

Comment: Consider add an explanation

Comment: This was actually a typo on my end. Good catch. I have updated my question because the code is still not working unfortunately. The bottom border will not appear!